# density joint function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I got a question and I was stuck for more than 15 minutes...

Here is the question,
[image]

And the question was:

Find F(1/2,2).

I tried to reason but the answer was different from what I got, here is the solution:
[image]

Can someone please explain to me why the answer is separated into two parts. I really don't get it!

Thank you!

For the marginal density of Y2.

Here is the solution,

[image]

Comment: It looks like the separated it into two parts simply because they already had part of the answer.  Maybe they figured it would be easier to find the remainder than to find the whole from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why they did it that way, other than they already had part of the answer so didn't want to start over from scratch.

Noting that the support is a triangle $(0,{-}1)(0,1)(1,0)$, then the range $y_1\leq 1/2, y_2\leq 2$ covers the trapezoid $(0,{-}1)(\tfrac{1}{2},{-\tfrac{1}{2}})(\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2})(0,1)$, this is split into three regions, the triangle $(0,-1),(-\tfrac{1}{2},-\tfrac{1}{2})(0,-\tfrac{1}{2})$, the rectangle $(0,-\tfrac{1}{2}),(\tfrac{1}{2},-\tfrac{1}{2}),(\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2})(0,\tfrac{1}{2})$ and the triangle $(0,\tfrac{1}{2}),(\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2})(0,1)$.

That last triangle is the part done in your solition, the first two shapes would have been the part done in part (a).

$\begin{align}
f(y_1,y_2) & = 30\, y_1\, y_2^2 \;\mathbf 1_{[-1,1]}(y_2)\;\mathbf 1_{[0,\min(1,1+y_2, 1-y_2)]}(y_1)
\\[2ex]
F(x,y) & = \int_{-1}^{\min(y,1)} \int_0^{\min(1+y_2, 1-y_2, 1)} 30 y_1 y_2 \operatorname dy_1\operatorname dy_2 
\\[2ex]
F(1/2,2) & = \int_{-1}^{1}\int_0^{\min(1/2,1+y_2, 1-y_2)} 30 y_1 y_2^2 \operatorname dy_1\operatorname dy_2 
\\[1ex]
 & = \int_{-1}^{-1/2}\int_0^{1+y_2} 30 y_1 y_2^2\operatorname d y_1\operatorname d y_2
+ \int_{-1/2}^{1/2} \int_0^{1/2} 30 y_1 y_2^2 \operatorname d y_1\operatorname d y_2
+ \color{navy}{\int_{1/2}^1 \int_0^{1-y_2} 30 y_1 y_2^2 \operatorname d y_1\operatorname d y_2}
\\[1ex]
 & = 15 \int_{-1}^{-1/2} y_2^2 (1+y_2)^2 \operatorname d y_2
+ \frac {15}4 \int_{-1/2}^{1/2} y_2^2\operatorname d y_2
+ \color{navy}{15 \int_{1/2}^1 y_2^2(1-y_2)^2 \operatorname d y_2}
\\[1ex]
 & = \Big[3y_2^3+\frac{15}{2} y_2^4+3y_2^5\Big]_{y_2=-1}^{y_2=-1/2}
+ \Big[\frac 5 4 y_2^3\Big]_{y_2=-1/2}^{y_2=1/2}
+ \color{navy}{\Big[3y_2^3-\frac{15}{2} y_2^4+3y_2^5\Big]_{y_2=1/2}^{y_2=1}}
\\[1ex]
 & = \frac{1}{4}
+ \frac{5}{16}
+ \color{navy}{\frac{1}{4}}
\\[1ex]
& = \frac {13}{16}
\end{align}$

---

I'd have approached it thus:

Noting that the support is a triangle $(0,-1)(0,1)(1,0)$, then the range $y_1\leq 1/2, y_2\leq 2$ covers the trapezoid $(0,-1)(1/2,-1/2)(1/2)(1/2)(0,1)$, the integration is easiest done by:

$\begin{align}
f(y_1,y_2) & = 30 y_1 y_2^2 \operatorname{\bf 1}_{[0,1]}(y_1)\operatorname{\bf 1}_{[y_1-1,1-y_1]}(y_2)
\\[2ex]
F(x,y) & = \int_0^{\min(x,1)}\int_{y_1-1}^{\min(y,1-y_1)} f(y_1,y_2)\operatorname dy_2\operatorname dy_1
\\[1ex]
F(1/2,2) & = \int_0^{1/2} \int_{y_1-1}^{{1-y_1}} 30 y_1 y_2^2\operatorname d y_2\operatorname dy_1
\\[1ex] & = 20\int_0^{1/2} y_1(1-y_1)^3\operatorname d y_1
\\[1ex] & = \Big[10y_1^2 -20y_1^3+15y_1^4-4y_1^5\Big]_{y_1=0}^{y_1=1/2}
\\[1ex] & = \frac {13} {16}
\end{align}$

Comment: Thank you so much!! Your approach is much clearer than the solution!!

Comment: Sorry... I have another question for this one. How would you find the marginal density function of Y2? I looked at the solution, it has been separted into two parts...again???!!! Why?

Comment: @Blackgirl5 $\begin{align}
f(y_1,y_2) & = 30\, y_1\, y_2^2 \quad\mathbf 1_{[0,1]}(y_1)\;\mathbf 1_{[y_1-1,1-y_1]}(y_2)
\\[1ex]
 & = 30\, y_1\, y_2^2 \quad\mathbf 1_{[-1,1]}(y_2)\;\mathbf 1_{[0,\min(1+y_2,1-y_2)]}(y_1)
\\[2ex]
f_{Y_2}(y_2) & = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y_1,y_2)\operatorname dy_1
\\[0ex]
 & = 30\, y_2^2\;\mathbf 1_{[-1,1]}(y_2)\int_0^{\min(1+y_2,1-y_2)} y_1 \operatorname dy_1
\\[1ex] & = 15\, y_2^2\;\mathbf 1_{[-1,1]}(y_2)\; (\min(1+y_2,1-y_2))^2
\\[1ex] & = 15\, (y_2^2-2|y_2^3|+y_2^4)\quad\mathbf 1_{[-1,1]}(y_2)
\end{align}$

Comment: Can I say that I don't understand the notation you used...

Comment: I have edited my question. I don't understand why for both parts, the integration would be from 0 to (1+y2) or (1-y2). And why the domain is that for both parts. Thank you!